# How to determine the running time T(n) for a given recursive function?

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence

How to determine the recurrence formula of T(n) for the next function?

```
if(N == 0)
  return 1;

s = 0;

x = function(N/3);

for(i = 1; i <= N; i++){
  s += x;
}

return s;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify a recursive call `x = function(N/3)` which complexity is `T(n/3)`. What follows are `N` additions, so `N` operations to account for.

Therefore the recurrence relation for the complexity of this function is

```
T(n) = T(n/3) + n
```

Hence

```
T(n) = O(n.log3(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Master Theorem:

T(n) = a*T(n/b) + C * n^k (with a,b,C > 0, k is in N).

case 1: a < b^k --> T(n) is in Θ (n^k)

case 2: a = b^k --> T(n) is in Θ (n^k * log (n))

case 3: a > b^k --> T(n) is in Θ (n^logb a)

In your case T(n) = 1 * T(n/3) + С * n^1.

a = 1, b = 3, k = 1 --> T(n) is in Θ (n).